# Document non-negativity using assertions rather than unsigned type - how?

Tags: c++, assert, unsigned

When reading the "Google C++ Style Guide", I am confused by this sentence "document that a variable is non-negative using assertions, don't use unsigned type" in Page 22. There is an example:

```
//this code will never terminate!
unsigned int i=10;
for(i;i>=0;--i)
{
    cout<<i<<endl;
}
```

If I must use unsigned int type, and how can I avoid this mistake?

Comment: I didn't read the guide. But I think they are referring to problem of assigning a negative value to an unsigned type. This will cause overflow and it's very hard to spot this kind of errors because an unsigned type can't be checked for non negativity. So they are suggesting that instead of using unsigned types in order to state that this variable should be positive use a singed type that can be checked for negativity and if this variable is negative assert.

Comment: It means that if a parameter is supposed to be non-negative, don't document that by declaring the parm to be unsigned.  Instead add an assertion that the parm is `>=` zero.

Comment: IMHO, I highly recommend NOT using the Google C+++ Style Guide.

Comment: why you don't recommend use the Google C++ Style Guide? @user3344003

Comment: As with the other thousand of code style guides, they form a pattern so that a team may co-operate with consistency, but the guide itself is not golden rule. Indeed, most of them are based on personal preference like TAB vs SPACE, etc. and for this specific unsigned concern, you can indeed do either way, an explicit checking works, while a misuse of unsigned type should give signed/unsigned conversion warning.

Comment: I dislike that style guide, but my reasons are different. We're way over into opinion territory here.

Comment: IMO it's way better to document the interface with use of unsigned type than with an assert which forces you to check the implementation for the expected range.

Comment: The Goole C++Style guide looks like it was written by someone right out of college with zero pragmatic programming experience. You can find a lot of detailed critiques on line. E.g., https://www.linkedin.com/today/post/article/20140503193653-3046051-why-google-style-guide-for-c-is-a-deal-breaker    Historically, programmers have jumped on stupid things just because they came from the flavor-of the month company. Another example, the idiotic hungarian notation from Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

clang++ says:

```
test.cc:7:8: warning: comparison of unsigned expression >= 0 is always true [-Wtautological-compare]
for(i;i>=0;--i)
      ~^ ~
```

g++ says:

```
test.cc:7:10: warning: comparison of unsigned expression >= 0 is always true [-Wtype-limits]
```

> how can I avoid this mistake?

Which mistake are you referring to? The mistake of using the Google C++ style guide or the mistake of using an always-true condition as a terminating condition in a loop?

For the first one, don't use it. Especially not the advice you quote: signed types are far, far more dangerous when used unskillfully in C++ (and C).

For the second one,

1) use a compiler with good diagnostics (even if you're using something else for production, give it a pass through clang)

2) rewrite your loop, there are many ways to do so:

```
for(unsigned int n = 0; n <= i; ++n) {
    std::cout << i-n << '\n';
}
```

or

```
do {
    std::cout << i << '\n';
} while(i-- > 0);
```

or whatever you fancy

Answer (score 0):

It is saying: Don't rely on the "self-documenting" feature of unsigned types to show that they are only supposed to be positive. Use signed types and check the values.

The following will terminate correctly when i "wraps" around because -1 is equal to INT_MAX in this case.

`for (unsigned int i = 9; i != -1; i--)`

Comment: //this code will never terminate!
unsigned int i=10;
for(i;i>=0;--i)
{
    cout<<i<<endl;
}
If I must use unsigned int type, and how can I avoid this mistake? Thank you.

Comment: Try something like the following: for (unsigned int i = 9; i != -1; i--). I've updated my answer with this info.